# How to change the dialog's button colors for a Material Date picker

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-datepicker

I'm using Material components to create a DatePicker. From what I understand, `colorPrimary` is used to determine the color of the section at the top of the dialog, as well as the colors for the text on the buttons, specifically `CANCEL` and `OK`.

Going through the documentation, I can't seem to find a way to change *just* the color of the buttons at the bottom ? Is it possible to do that ?

current code:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.DatePicker" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearanceSmallComponent">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearanceMediumComponent">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent
    </item>
    <item name="materialCalendarHeaderTitle">@style/MyHeaderTitle</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimarySurface">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyHeaderTitle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.HeaderTitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeMaterialCalendarTextButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog.Flush">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">16dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.MediumComponent">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">16dp</item>
</style>
```

[image: My Dialog]

Comment: Try using the `colorOnSecondary`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
builder.setTheme(R.style.MaterialCalendarTheme)
```

and then define:

```
  <style name="MaterialCalendarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/TextButton</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/TextButton</item>
  </style>
  <style name="TextButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/...</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/...</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: ah wow, so simple, can't believe I didn't think of that, thank you

Comment: doesn't work with `DatePickerDialog`